# How to build a weekly programmable web-based timer?

Tags: timer

I am trying to figure out what is the best possible solution to create a website to function as a weekly programmable timer; after searching many hours I keep coming up empty handed.

I tried to start development on a web page. This is where I wound up:
http://www.gstrip.tk

I have a complete lack of knowledge on how to progress from this point.

- How do I store the timers?
- How do I make the server search for timers.
- Then how do I execute a function such as a simple html request when the stored time for that day matches the current time?

This has been a huge stumbling block for me I assumed there would be an open source web based weekly programmable timer somewhere that I could modify but it appears nearly to be not available.

If it is already posted could you provide a link or something anything as I have searched fairly regularly the last couple of weeks with no results using different terms both on google and on stack. Maybe the syntax of my search is wrong somehow and this may be the reason for the lack of results IDK but I could sure use someone who is understanding and willing to level with me on this issue.

Comment: What server-side language do you wish to use? Timers can be stored in a database - they are just data that consists of a time when the computer should do something. You can then get the server to check if any timers are due to go off using cron (on GNU/Linux) or Scheduler (on Windows).

Comment: Thanks halfer so glad someone responded this has been really bugging me why I couldn't find anything on this. So basically my question is what is the most practical way of doing this what languages, database, etc should be used. I essentially have cpanel access to my website which should allow for cron job creation I believe.What will happen is these timers will essentially control an IOT device called a nodemcu it will turn output pins on and off fairly simple in principal. But being new to stuff other than basic html minimal java etc I feel it was important to ask the experts the best route.

Comment: If you're using GNU/Linux, PHP is a very easy way to start. Create a MySQL database, create a table `timer` (e.g. `id, due_date, action_code`, `is_triggered`) where `due_date` is the time to trigger an action, and `action_code` corresponds to what it should do when it triggers, and `is_triggered` is set to `true` when the timer has triggered. Then set up a cron every minute to call `timer.php` which connects to the database, finds any non-triggered timers that are past due, runs the associated action, and marks them as triggered.

Comment: ok so I guessed everything that I needed to do and the best way to do it but wasn't sure if their was a smoother easier way of doing this ... For instance. Scan for timers once a day add the timers once every 24hours then directly add any timers that are newly created to stop cron from having to continually execute php although this is probably not all that heavy on the server as I am thinking a simple read operation like this shouldn't do all that much really. halfer man you are my savior the only thing better would be to have seen some example code or someone who has done similar open source

Comment: Anyone who reads this feel free to share more information, source code examples, urls of anything that would relate to this. A big thanks @halfer for making me feel a lot less mushroom like lol.

Comment: You're welcome. Cron is very inexpensive to run, and a check once a minute will not add any noticeable load to the system. All it will do is create a database connection, run some code and finish - extremely lightweight. There are other ways of doing it, but keeping timers in memory will take up more memory than just making a check every minute.